# How do you get descriptions of the available `shopt` options?

Tags: bash, shopt

What is the canonical way for accessing the **local** documentation on any available Shell Options builtin with `shopt`?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and can run `help shopt` to get a description of what `shopt` does:

```
shopt: shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname ...]
    Set and unset shell options.
    ...
```

I can list the various Shell Options and their values (`shopt` or `shopt -p`). But how do I find out what each one actually does without leaving the comfort of my Linux box? I'm not looking for [the descriptions online](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html). Is there a `man` page or something I'm missing?

Comment: Quick Trick ~ `man bash | grep "shopt"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the "shell builtin commands" section of `man bash`; it has an entry for `shopt` that describes all of the available shell options. Here is an excerpt:

```
   shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname ...]

   [...]

          autocd  If  set,  a command name that is the name of a directory
                  is executed as if it were the argument to  the  cd  com-
                  mand.  This option is only used by interactive shells.
          cdable_vars
                  If  set,  an  argument to the cd builtin command that is
                  not a directory is assumed to be the name of a  variable
                  whose value is the directory to change to.
          cdspell If set, minor errors in the spelling of a directory com-
                  ponent in a cd command will be  corrected.   The  errors
                  checked for are transposed characters, a missing charac-
                  ter, and one character too many.   If  a  correction  is
                  found,  the corrected file name is printed, and the com-
                  mand proceeds.  This option is only used by  interactive
                  shells.

          [...]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find the list of options in the man page under the description of the `shopt` builtin. To open the man page at the list of options, you can use the `less` feature that lets you run a command such as a search when it starts:

```
PAGER='less "+/^ *The list of shopt"' man bash
```

To view this documentation in Info:

```
info --index shopt bash
```

If you want to extract the relevant part of the man page:

```
man bash | sed '/^ *The list of shopt/, /^ *suspend / p' | sed '$d'
```

or (nicer, as it removes the indentation)

```
man bash | awk '
    /^ *The list of shopt/ {indent=match($0, /[^ ]/)}
    /^ *suspend / && RSTART==indent {exit}
    indent {print substr($0, indent)}'
```

If you want to extract the description of one option (e.g. `sourcepath`):

```
man bash | awk -v target=sourcepath '
    /^ *The list of shopt/ {shopt=1}
    shopt && $1==target {getline; indent=match($0, /[^ ]/)}
    indent {if (match($0, /[^ ]/)>=indent) print substr($0, indent); else exit}'
```