# Why No manual entry for shopt?

Tags: man, shopt

man-db is already the newest version.
[image]

shopt can run,but no **man shopt** info.
[image]

Comment: 1) Please don't post pictures of text; 2) `shopt` is a Bash builtin - see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106858/how-do-you-get-descriptions-of-the-available-shopt-options) (possible dupe?) for guidance.

Comment: Just write shopt and hit enter and you will see the list of args that you can pass to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shopt` is a `bash` builtin. If you run `which shopt`, you will see that there isn't actually a command called `"shopt"`. Thus `man shopt` makes as little sense as `man cd`. The descriptions of how `shopt` and `cd` work belong in `man bash`.